# React context updating values with Context.Consumer but not with contextType

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I tried to use React context in a React component but I have some troubles.

In my `Component.jsx` I have a render method like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <NavigationProvider>
        <ShipmentsContext.Consumer>
          {({ isDetailsVisible }) => (
            <div>
              {this.renderHeader(isDetailsVisible)}
            </div>
          )}
        </ShipmentsContext.Consumer>
      </NavigationProvider>
    );
  }
```

---

This works good and `isDetailsVisible` is updating as I want.

But I want to remove `<ShipmentsContext.Consumer>` and use `contextType` but when I get `isDetailsVisible` in my `renderHeader` method, it always set to `false`and no updating...

Here is the code of the `renderHeader`

- Using `<ShipmentsContext.Consumer>` : (`isDetailsVisible` is updating)

```
renderHeader(isDetailsVisible) {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <Searchbar className={classNames({ [classes.nodeTranslated]: isDetailsVisible})}/>
    );
  }
```

- Using `contextType`: (`isDetailsVisible` is **NOT** updating => always set to default value)

```
renderHeader() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { isDetailsVisible } = this.context;

    return (
      <Searchbar className={classNames({ [classes.nodeTranslated]: isDetailsVisible })}/>
    );
  }
```

Any idea? Thanks !

Comment: Draw back of Context type is, you can have only one context type. Are you sure there are no other context types for the same component? That's an usual mistake wet to contexts. Also, please post code of context types. Whole component would be better to check

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your trouble context is `ShipmentsContext`, do you by chance miss a corresponding `ShipmentsContext.Provider`?

You drop `<ShipmentsContext.Consumer>` and keep the `<ShipmentsContext.Provider>`. The context consumer can be set with help of [`contextType`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype) as static class field:

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  static contextType = ShipmentsContext;
  ...
}

// When you don't want to/cannot use public class 
// fields syntax, this is the alternative:
// MyComp.contextType = ShipmentsContext;
```

Here is a simple test sample:

```js
const ShipmentsContext = React.createContext({
  isDetailsVisible: "false from default"
});

class MyComp extends React.Component {
  static contextType = ShipmentsContext;

  render() {
    return this.renderHeader();
  }

  renderHeader() {
    return <p>{JSON.stringify(this.context)}</p>;
  }
}

const App = () => {
  // state realized with React Hooks. You could also use a 
  // class component and `setState` for App
  const [contextValue, setContextValue] = React.useState({
    isDetailsVisible: "true from Provider"
  });

  return (
    <ShipmentsContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setContextValue({ isDetailsVisible: "UPDATED true from Provider" })
        }
      >
        Update Context
      </button>
      <MyComp />
    </ShipmentsContext.Provider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-vMEjoeSlzpWvres5mDlxmSKxx6jAmDNY4zCt712YCI0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-QQt6MpTdAD0DiPLhqhzVyPs1flIdstR4/R7x4GqCvZ4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

By clicking on the "Update Context" button, the context will be provided a new value and `renderHeader` will also get notice of the change.

Let me know, if that fits your case. Good luck!